# Match multiple regular expressions against a single column (and tabulate the matches)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to know how many items/documents get matched by a regular expression. The final result should look like this format:

```
data = [['Regular Expression 1', 10], ['Regular Expression 2', 15]]
final = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Regular Expression', 'Count'])
```

Here is the example dataset of text documents

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3,4,5], 
                    'b' : ['hi whatever something',
                           'foo', 'fat a a a foo', 'cat', 'fat']})
```

here are the regular expressions that count up the data

```
g1 = foo['b'][foo['b'].str.contains(r'(?=.*foo)(?=.*fat)|(\bwhatever\b)',regex=True)].count()
g2 = foo['b'][foo['b'].str.contains(r'\bfat\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}?foo\b',regex=True)].count()
g1  # 2 
g2  # 1
```

How do I concatenate (the pandas equivalent `rbind` in R) the data rows? So I can get the data to look like object "Final"?

I tried `pd.concat([g1,g2], axis=0)` but I get this error message from using concat: `cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`

Comment: Well you already got the regex matching working, so your question boils down to "How do I concatenate (the pandas equivalent `rbind` in R) rows?". Say "concatenate [into a dataframe or Series]" rather than "tabulate the results" in your title, because "tabulate" means "generate a frequency-table, counting the frequency of each value", i.e. pandas `value_counts()`.

Comment: There are [310 questions on "pandas concatenate rows"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pandas+concatenate+rows+is%3Aq); this is a duplicate; the only issue is of which.

Comment: @smci There's quite a few things going on here, concat isn't enough to solve this in its entirety.

Comment: @cs95 but the OP already solved their regex matching. Then it boils down to "apply multiple regexes against a df, tabulate the (frequency-table of the) results (into a DataFrame). (Update: OP did actually want tabulation, my comment above it was not clear to me they wanted it)

Comment: @smci They solved it in a sense, yes, but you'd need to know what you're doing to get from their current output to their expected output, especially considering they're applying their regex one at a time. I agree this is certainly related  to concatenating dataframes, but I would think carefully before closing it. I've also rebranded the question to be one of matching multiple regular expressions, versus one of concatenation, which should count for leaving it open. But that's just my 2c.

Comment: @cs95: Yes it should be left open, my bad. The multiple intent of the OP's question is only really apparent from the code intent, not from the word statement of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.contains` in a loop, then `concat` the results and call `sum`:

```
R = [r'(?=.*foo)(?=.*fat)|(\bwhatever\b)', r'\bfat\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}?foo\b']
df = pd.concat({r: foo['b'].str.contains(r) for r in R}, axis=1)

df.sum().rename_axis('regex').reset_index(name='count')

                               regex  count
0  (?=.*foo)(?=.*fat)|(\bwhatever\b)      2
1      \bfat\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}?foo\b      1
```